# Interpolique: transparently preventing SQL Injection and XSS with base64 encoding, what happened?

Tags: security, xss, sql-injection

For the [keynote at The Next HOPE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_TCmJHaMb0) a couple of years ago, Dan Kaminsky unveiled [Interpolique](http://dankaminsky.com/interpolique/) (the talk is really fun btw).  The problem he raised was how to defend against injection attacks, including SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), and other injection vulnerabilities.  For example, Unicode makes escaping characters useless and that prepared statements are a PITA.

His fix was to convert strings to base64 during transit.  In SQL, for example, one can simply pad the SQL call with a decode64 eval().  It's much easier than prepared statements, little (if any) impact on DB performance, transparent to users of the DB, and native implementation within programming languages could make usage transparent for the programmer both in terms of use and server performance. Similar techniques can be applied to defend against XSS and all cross-language communication.  But, outside of a couple of blog articles written at the time, I can't find mention of it anywhere.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened?  What happened is the same thing that happens to many good ideas in the security space: it went nowhere, for reasons outside of the inventor's control.  It is a cool idea, but it requires adoption by frameworks and application developers.  And, for better or worse, there is not a lot of demand for security solutions like this.  For most developers, security is a secondary consideration.  Many application developers don't think they have a problem and don't perceive a need for a solution (most of them are probably fooling themselves, but so it goes).  And many of the developers who *are* aware of XSS, think they can avoid it by just being careful (that's a dubious proposition, as it is too easy to make a single inadvertent mistake that hoses the security of your whole site, but hey, if they don't feel a need for it, they ain't gonna adopt it).

Please do understand that Interpolique is not primarily about SQL injection.  You describe it as being about SQL injection, but that isn't its primary contribution.  Its primary contribution is helping to defend against XSS and other injection attacks.  Kaminsky's talk does discuss how to use Interpolique to prevent SQL injection, but I suspect that is primarily a pedagogical device.  Interpolique is a general defense against injection attacks, of which SQL injection and XSS are two examples.  SQL injection is easier to understand and simpler to understand than XSS, so it was probably simpler to explain the ideas behind Interpolique in the context of SQL injection than XSS.  Any security researcher should immediately see how they apply to the context of XSS, which is the more important and challenging problem.  As others have said, prepared statements are a "good-enough" solution to SQL injection for practical purposes (there are indeed some cases that are not handled by prepared statements, but they can probably handled by escaping/validation plus careful code audits), so that's not where Interpolique is most useful.

The security technology in this space that has seen the most take-up is [context-aware auto-escaping](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2009/03/reducing-xss-by-way-of-automatic.html), such as [that implemented in Google's ctemplate](http://google-ctemplate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/auto_escape.html).  That requires framework support, but is arguably even better for developers than Interpolique, because in most situations it requires no additional effort from developers: escaping is done automatically for them.  In addition, it is better for security, too: escaping is done by default, so the defaults are secure and developers have to take some explicit step to disable the security measures.

This question might have gotten more informed responses on the IT Security stack exchange.
(I can't believe one person actually wrote "Dunno who is that Dan Kaminsky guy, but he has no clue."  I hope that was a joke!  Kaminsky is one of the most prominent and respected researchers/practitioners in computer security.)  You can find Interpolique and similar technologies discussed on IT security at the following questions: [Whitelisting DOM elements to defeat XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1238/971), [Escaping JavaScript constants](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1327/971).

Comment: Okay,okay. He is one of the most prominent blah-blah-blah, with all my respect to ranks and stuff. However, his idea is no more than just a **prepared statement** with named placeholders. So, he just contradicts with himself.

Comment: `(there are indeed some cases that are not handled by prepared statements, but they can probably handled by escaping/validation plus careful code audits)` - interpolique has no solution for that either.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, you know the saying: *when you are in a hole, stop digging*.  I see you digging yourself deeper.  It is not remotely accurate to say that Interpolique is nothing more than a prepared statement.  You seem to continue to think that Interpolique is primarily about SQL injection -- but it is not.  As I wrote in my answer at great length, Interpolique is about more than just stopping SQL injection; it is also about stopping XSS.  As a result, you have dismissed Interpolique prematurely, without really understanding it.

Comment: There is one problem with your answer. Despite of great length, it lacks the matter. The mechanism. The actual technology description. I'd be glad to learn it, if there will be some explanation other than 2 presentation slides and handful paragraphs of praise and admiration.

Comment: And yet his slides ARE on SQL injection. `"No developer has ever written a parameterized query without a gun to his head"`. LOL, go try to say that on SO nowadays. You'd be torn in pieces in a matter of seconds :)

Comment: Slides 40-43 solution is JS-based. That's just an answer to the OP.

Comment: You are bad ally. Dan is the right guy, he looks for the destructive analysis, not praise. You criticize him not, thus you do no good to his project.

Comment: Well, DW kinda skunked my A/B test, but the questions certainly got [upvoted](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/interpolique-transparently-preventing-sql-injection-and-xss-with-base64-encodin#comment19695_12512) at Staack Sec : )

Answer (score -1):

The example given by YCS will be more clear if you see what is actually returned:

```
php > echo mysql_real_escape_string("1; DROP TABLE users;");
1; DROP TABLE users;
php > echo mysql_real_escape_string("1'; DROP TABLE users;");
1\'; DROP TABLE users;
```

This function *partially* mitigates *some* vectors for SQL injection, but in no way it provides full protection against it. You still must use input validation and output escaping to prevent it.

Comment: *This function* has absolutely nothing to do with injections. It does not intended for protection at all, neither full or partial. Neither  input validation has anything to do with injections.

Comment: Successful SQL injection requires that the injected data forms a syntactically correct SQL statement. So if you block or escape characters that are required to make it correct, you have _partially_ blocked the injection. 

Partially, because sometimes there are many ways to bypass the filter. On the other hand during pentesting I've seen many cases where I could inject _something_ but due to how the query was constructed I wasn't able to make it exploitable.

Comment: There is no point in blocking or escaping whatever characters. this idea is your essential problem. Format your literals properly instead, and have injection blocked 100%

Comment: Your advice is equally helpful as "write your code correctly". If it could be applied to real life, there would be no need to use WAFs and IDSs. Unfortunately it cannot - people use different 3rd party applications and libraries, which are of different quality. So input validation and escaping make a lot of sense if you prefer resistance to practical attacks over philosophical purity.

Comment: Quite contrary.  input validation and escaping is a sure way to injection.

Comment: Can you give example scenarios?

Comment: For second order injections to work your app still needs to allow backslashes, apostrophes etc. And if it's for a field that expects an integer, it's just badly broken input validation in the first place. And if you only allow digits, no first or second order injection will be possible.

Comment: and what if I need to save not only gigits?

Comment: Same story. Define what charset or structure you need and allow only that. That's the first thing you should do on input, not only for the sake of stopping SQL injections but any other attack that bases on unexpected input.

Comment: go on tell Stack Overflow admins to define such a charset. And then try to post any code

Comment: Sure, I do this all the time at my work. In the first place, if you look at StackOverflow URLs there's numeric question identifier, which might map into internal database fields. This is something that should be definitely validated.

Comment: Then there are all the messages which look like a completely free text, but really aren't. They are Unicode strings, which may contain basic HTML formatting. Here you also need to ensure that no XSS vectors are sneaked through Markdown tags. If SO uses parametrized queries for SQL then there's probably not much need for escaping these.
On the other hand, SO might use raw SQL pieces as input into parametrized queries, which is typical in search, views etc. In such case lack of input validation **is** a recipe for SQL injection.

Comment: You have gone so far from the topic. Your idea of input validation is flawed. Think of it

Comment: You have a weird and very unusual idea of application security. Get used to it.

Comment: Yeah, unusual. Exactly. I don't share all the usual PHP cargo cult gospels and superstitions. That's the point. And I am quite used to it already :)

Answer (score -3):

Dunno who is that Dan Kaminsky guy, but he has no clue.

- Escaping *strings* is not useless *when used properly* (and, as a matter of fact, escaping strings has nothing to do with injections at all)
- Prepared statements is not that PITA if used with a little smartness

So, both his assumptions are plainly wrong. That's enough to make whatever his framework obsolete.

May be he just realized that soon after releasing his idea - a possible reason why you never heard of that approach again.

By the way, Mysql, for example, has [it's own base16 encoding facility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) out of the box:

```
mysql> SELECT 0x5061756c;
       -> 'Paul'
```

require no  idealistic projects to implement. 
it is not widely used though.

Yet I have to admit that unlike escaping, it won't fail in case of improper use.

Say, a notorious case of improper escaping use (PHP/Mysql)

```
$spoiled_data = "1; DROP TABLE users;"
$spoiled_data = mysql_real_escape_string($spoiled_data);
$query        = "SELECT * FROM users where id=$spoiled_data";
```

when ported to hex strings way

```
$spoiled_data = "1; DROP TABLE users;"
$spoiled_data = '0x'.bin2hex ($spoiled_data);
$query        = "SELECT * FROM users where id=$spoiled_data";
```

will be pretty safe.

Comment: Dan Kaminsky is one of the world's forefront leading security researchers, and is responsible for the invention of DNSSec for example. I do however agree with you that prepared statements are a more well tested and better way to prevent SQL injections

Comment: Can you explain that first statement?  I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around string escaping not being useless but also having nothing to do with the problem...

Comment: @Indolering That's quite simple thing. Escaping is just a string formatting facility. Frankly, it escapes string delimiters. Thus, when you need it - you need it despite of security matters, just because a string may contain a delimiter that needs to be escaped. So, you have to escape your strings unconditionally - not because of injections but because of special chars. Yet when it's inapplicable, for the numbers for example -it's completely useless, as there is no delimiters - so, nothing to escape. as a side effect it prevents injections, **but for strings only,** inapplicable anywhere else.

Comment: Dan Kaminsky's point is that people commonly forget to escape, or incorrectly escape strings.  This is partially due to the differing types of string escapes that must be done depending on the *context* that the string will be interpreted under.  It is further complicated by order of operation.  His solution reduces all that complexity because you only ever need to escape a string in exactly one way.  It removed programmer error and helps "future proof" code should an old escape method be found insufficient.

Comment: The other feature of Interpolique is that it will cause things to break in a fantastic manner if a developer forgets to employ it.  With normal escaping, it is often non-obvious if it isn't employed.  This leads to security flaws that may lay around in production code without being noticed until after they have been exploited.

Comment: _"it will cause things to break in a fantastic manner if a developer forgets to employ it"_ - which is actually very good feature, because you will have a large chance of discovering this early during functional testing, not when the application gets hacked.